# Problem with Memory Allocation while Using Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, allocation

I am attempting to use with a structure that uses data allocation. Despite getting the correct outputs within each function, I am getting an overflow error when these functions are ran through a thread. The current code I have is:

```
#include <iostream> // cout, endl
#include <thread>   // thread

using namespace std;

// a structure to hold parameters to pass to a thread
struct StatData
{
    // the number of numbers
    int n;
    // the array of numbers
    double *numbers;
};

void average(StatData *data, double *avg) {
    int id;
    int size = data->n;
    double sum = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum += data->numbers[i];
    }
    *avg = sum / size;
}

void minimum(StatData *data, double *min) {
    int id;
    int size = data->n;
    *min = data->numbers[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (*min > data->numbers[i]){
            *min = data->numbers[i];
        }
    }
}

void maximum(StatData *data, double *max) {
    int id;
    int size = data->n;
    *max = data->numbers[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (*max < data->numbers[i]){
            *max = data->numbers[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // checking if arguments were passed
    if (argc <= 1) {
        cout << "No numbers were passed." << endl;
        cout << "At least one number needs to be entered." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // declaring worker threads
    thread avg_t, min_t, max_t;

    // variables for values
    double avg_v;
    double min_v;
    double max_v;

    // initalizing data structure to hold numbers
    StatData data;
    data.n = argc - 1;                  // the amount of numbers passed
    data.numbers = new double[data.n];  // allocating space for nums

    // Filling in the array with numbers using atof
    for (int i = 0; i < data.n; i++) {
        data.numbers[i] = atof(argv[i+1]); // converting string to double
    }

    // creating average thread
    avg_t = thread(average, &data, &avg_v);

    // creating minimum thread
    min_t = thread(minimum, &data, &min_v);

    // creating maximum thread
    max_t = thread(maximum, &data, &max_v);

    // wating for threads to finish
    avg_t.join();
    min_t.join();
    max_t.join();

    printf ("The average value is %d\n", &avg_v);
    printf ("The minimum value is %d\n", &min_v);
    printf ("The maximum value is %d\n", &max_v);

    // freeing up dynamically allocated space
    delete[] data.numbers;
}
```

When I run a ./test with values of 47, 58, and 6 I get a printed statement of:
The average value is -502425280
The minimum value is -502425288
The maximum value is -502425296

I'm not sure where I am going wrong that is causing the code to do this.

Comment: Does this depend on the use of threads? As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Oh, btw, use `std::vector`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing addresses of the values (`&avg_v` is a pointer to `avg_v`, which when printed as `%d`, will print a part of the value of the pointer itself).

To print the `double` values themselves, simply do

```
    printf ("The average value is %lf\n", avg_v);
    printf ("The minimum value is %lf\n", min_v);
    printf ("The maximum value is %lf\n", max_v);
```

Note that `%d` is for printing *integers*, for floating point values use `%f` or `%lf` (the two are equivalent).

`&` is only needed in `scanf` because `scanf` takes addresses of variables. `printf` takes actual values, so no need to pass addresses to it (unless you want to print the address of course).

---

Having that sorted out, the program can arguably be made simpler by making use of more C++ standard library features. To name a few: `std::vector`, `std::accumulate`, `std::min_element`, `std::max_element`, `std::async` (which creates a thread for you and returns a future) and lambdas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        std::cout << "No numbers were passed.\n"
            "At least one number needs to be entered.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<double> data;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        data.push_back(atof(argv[i]));
    }

    auto avg_f = std::async([&] {
        return accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0) / data.size();
    });
    auto min_f = std::async([&] {
        return *min_element(data.begin(), data.end());
    });
    auto max_f = std::async([&] {
        return *max_element(data.begin(), data.end());
    });

    // the 3 values are now being computed in parallel ...

    double avg_v = avg_f.get(); // get the values from futures (waits as necessary)
    double min_v = min_f.get();
    double max_v = max_f.get();

    std::cout << "The average value is " << avg_v << "\n";
    std::cout << "The minimum value is " << min_v << "\n";
    std::cout << "The maximum value is " << max_v << "\n";
}
```